# References: Remove white space in front of doi

Tags: hyperref, natbib, doi

In my references, there is a problem with the doi. When using `\usepackage{doi}`
I get hyperlinks, which is what I want. In combination with `\usepackage{apacite}`
however, I then have to suppress the doi prefix with `\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}` (otherwise  "doi:" would get displayed two times).
This combination of commands results in too many white spaces in front of the doi in the references section, e.g.:

[image: Too many white spaces in front of the doi]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[tocbib, natbibapa, nosectionbib]{apacite}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=blue}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{A,
   author = {Ackerman, P. L. and Beier, M. E. and Boyle, M. O.},
   title = {Working memory and intelligence: The same or different constructs?},
   journal = {Psychological Bulletin},
   volume = {131},
   pages = {30-60},
   DOI = {10.1037/0033-2909.131.1.30},
   year = {2005}
   }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{A}.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliography{test} 

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to remove one white space in front of the doi? Or does anybody know how to turn the doi's into hyperlinks without using the doi package?

Comment: If you look in the `bbl` file, you'll notice `\begin{APACrefDOI} \doi{10.1037/0033-2909.131.1.30}`.  See the space, between `\begin{APACrefDOI}` and `\doi`? Define `\renewcommand\doiprefix{\ignorespaces}` and you will get rid of this extra space.

Comment: Alternativelty, you can keep `\doiprefix` and set `\renewcommand\doitext{}` (which is the text you get from the `doi` package).

Comment: @HenriMenke that works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @HenriMenke would you like to write your comment up as an answer

Comment: @DaiBowen Considering that all code written by [HenriMenke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10995/henri-menke) is released in [the public domain](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/), I think you can move on and write that comment as an answer, especially since he didn't answered your message. The license reads: ` You can copy, modify, distribute and perform the work, even for commercial purposes, all without asking permission.`. It is kind of you to ask, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments of Henri Menke:

If you look in the `.bbl` file, you'll notice

```
\begin{APACrefDOI} \doi{10.1037/0033-2909.131.1.30} \end{APACrefDOI}
```

See the space, between `\begin{APACrefDOI}` and `\doi`? Define

```
\renewcommand\doiprefix{\ignorespaces}
```

and you will get rid of this extra space.

Alternativelty, you can keep `\doiprefix` and set `\renewcommand\doitext{}` (which is the text you get from the doi package).